# How to write a portion of text from current file to the beginning of another file?

Tags: files, region

I have written a function that extracts a portion of text from current file and writes it in another one:

```
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)

  ;; re-search "beg" point
  ;; re-search "end" point

  ;; define markers
  (let* ((beg (copy-marker ...))
         (end (copy-marker ...)))

    (write-region beg end filename t)))
```

Now I would like that all the text between `beg` and `end` is added at the beginning of `filename`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc string of `write-region` says:

> Optional fourth argument APPEND if non-nil means
> append to existing file contents (if any).  If it is a number,
> seek to that offset in the file before writing.

So call it like this:

```el
(write-region beg end filename 0)
```

but as you found out that overwrites the beginning of the file with the contents of the region. To *insert* the contents of the region, you can do something like this:

```el
   ...
   (let ((s (buffer-substring beg end)))
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect filename)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (insert s)
      (save-buffer)))
```

Comment: @NiclD I had not understand the meaning of "seek to that offset" in the doc string of `write-region`. However, with your code, whole contents of `filename` is replace by all text between `beg` and `end`. I need that whole original contents of `filename` is preserved.

Comment: Try it now and let me know if there are any problems - thanks!

Comment: Ok, now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: `(point-min)` is 1, not 0 (though 0, -1 etc works the same as 1 since goto-char does not check bounds), or simply use `(goto-char (point-min))`.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected it.

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab: if it answers your question, you should consider  whether to [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer. Click on the button with the ? mark in the SE bar above and to the right for more information on how the site works.